# Problems deleting song from jellyfin playlist by API call

Tags: jellyfin

I'm trying to delete a song from a jellyfin playlist by an API call. I use following DELETE request:
`https://rxyzm.ml/Playlists/<playlistID>/Items?entryIds=<songId>&api_key=<apiKey>`
When I execute this, the song doesn't get removed from the playlist and I get return code 204.

If I look in devtools network window and perform the action manually, I get the same request except for the api_key parameter.

When I perform the task manually, the song gets removed from the playlist. What am I missing here?

Another method I tried was editing the playlist xml file in `/var/lib/jellyfin/data/playlists` but that didn't seem to do anything either...

All other API calls work (including deleting a playlist). I already looked with wireshark and jellyfin actually receives the DELETE request.

I'm using Jellyfin version 10.8.8
OS: Linux
Architecture: Arm64

I found the following in the logs. Maybe this has something to do with it but I don't really know how i could fix this.

```
[2022-12-30 10:13:39.960 +00:00] [ERR] Error in metadata saver
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/var/lib/jellyfin/data/playlists/Actief/playlist.xml' because it is being used by another process.
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileStreamOptions options)
   at MediaBrowser.LocalMetadata.Savers.BaseXmlSaver.SaveAsync(BaseItem item, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MediaBrowser.Providers.Manager.ProviderManager.SaveMetadataAsync(BaseItem item, ItemUpdateType updateType, IEnumerable`1 savers)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I was working with the songId but had to use PlaylistItemId's